# Error when using complex file names for tar -> write in perl

Tags: perl, tar

While using tar->write() I am getting errors while using complex file names.

The code is:

```
my $filename= $archive_type."_".$from_date_time."_".$to_date_time."tar";
$tar->write($filename);
```

The error i get is:
Could not create filehandle for 'postProcessProbe_2010/6/23/3_2010/6/23/7.tar':

No such file or directory at test.pl line 24

If I change the $filename to a simple string like out.tar everything works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `/` is the directory separator on *nix systems (and, internally Windows treats `/` and `\` interchangeably) and I believe `tar` files, regardless of platform use it internally as the directory separator.

I do not think you can create file names containing `/` on either *nix or Windows based systems. Even if you could, that would probably create a whole bunch of headaches down the road.

It would be better in my humble opinion to switch to a saner date format such as `YYYYMMDD`.

Also, you are using string concatenation when `sprintf` would have been much clearer:

`my $filename= sprintf '%s_%s_%s.tar', $archive_type,  $from_date_time, , $to_date_time;`

Comment: Not just on Unix; on Windows, too.

Comment: @thcrist Note the **the** ;-)